# svn 0.3.33 module : Windows Error: [Error 2] : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, svn

I have checked out a folder from SVN to my desktop. Actually I need to extract the information like SVN revision no, URL and status for the specific file in the local working copy. Here is the line of code which I am using to extract those info.
file = svn.local.LocalClient(filePath[i][j])
fileInfo = file.info()

This works perfectly fine in my desktop. But the same thing when I tried to do it in my laptop it throws the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svn-0.3.22-py2.7.egg\svn\common.py", line 134, in export
    self.run_command('export', [self.**url_or_path, path])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svn-0.3.22-py2.7.egg\svn\common.py", line 29, in run_command
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Can anyone pls help me what is wrong? I have installed all the packages which I installed in my desktop. But don't know what is the problem exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to recheck that the files on your laptop and make sure:

- The files actually exist / are the correct files.
- They are in the directory you are trying to access them from.
- The file names are spelled correctly.

If the system could not find the file specified it means something is missing / misplaced, or the file you are trying to access is not spelled the same as the one you actually want. Its most likely a simple error that could be found by just looking over everything and making sure its all the same as your desktop.

Comment: I replaced the whole Python27 folder in laptop from my desktop. Also i checked the file names which i am trying to access., It is all fine. But still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Actually the problem was with subversion command line client version. The client version need to be higher than the TortoiseSVN server version, whereas mine was a lower version which created this problem. Now it works fine :)